# How to Customise Toast in Android?

Tags: android, toast

Is it possible to make Customize Toast in Android. like if can we place in it image icon and place button.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the regular makeText() and handle the [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#getView%28%29) to set an image next to see the next.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView tv = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
if (null!=tv) {
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, 0, 0, 0);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_toast));
```

Comment: interesting...lt but worth post

Comment: Yes for future reference, IMO that's the cleanest solution when you need just an icon. The TextView also take a CharSequence so you can put some Spannable with all kids of things in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any view in a Toast using [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setView%28android.view.View%29). 
However, I'm not quite sure why you would want to place a button in it, as a Toast will rapidly disappear. Taken from the officiel developer site :

> When the view is shown to the user,
>   appears as a floating view over the
>   application. It will never receive
>   focus. The user will probably be in
>   the middle of typing something else.
>   The idea is to be as unobtrusive as
>   possible, while still showing the user
>   the information you want them to see.

So the toast should only be used to display information. For more complex interactions, you can use a Dialog.

Comment: Heyy Gregory..is it possible to handle button event from Toast?

Comment: I never tried and wouldn't do it, a Toast is just a temporary display. If you really need a button, consider using a Dialog (and eventually add a timer to dismiss it after a given time)

Answer (score 1):

Toast is non focus able.Adding button did not make sense. However you can display information.You can also control its visibility means u can hide and show 
by making few changes in Toast class.

Answer (score 1):

**XML FILE**

```
enter code here`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:background="#DAAA"
          >
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/droid"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
```

'

**JAVA CODE**

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```